# PHP - Searching in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following situation:

- I have the next multidimensional array:

  ```
    $numbers = array (
        "one_digit" => array (1,2,3,4,5),
        "two_digits" => array (20,21,22,23,24,25),
        "three_digits" => array (301,302,303,304,304),
        "mixed_digits" => array (9,29,309,1)
    );
  ```
- I need a way to search in the $numbers array for the following:

  -- search if number 20 is in any $numbers array and echo where it is found
  ex. $find1 = m_array_search("20", $numbers); echo "i've found the searched value in ".$find1." subarray of $numbers";
  result: "i've found the searched value in two_digits subarray of $numbers"

  -- search if number 1 is in any $numbers array and echo where it is found
  ex. $find2 = m_array_search("1", $numbers); echo "i've found the searched value in ".$find2." subarray of $numbers";
  result: "i've found the searched value in two_digits,mixed_digits subarray of $numbers"

Thus function must be able to spot presence in one or many "subarrays". Sorry if I've misused the term "subarray".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) in a loop -

```
$numbers = array (
    "one_digit" => array (1,2,3,4,5),
    "two_digits" => array (20,21,22,23,24,25),
    "three_digits" => array (301,302,303,304,304),
    "mixed_digits" => array (9,29,309,1)
);

function search_value($array, $value)
{
  $result = array();
  foreach($array as $key => $sub) {
    // check if element present in sub array
    if(array_search($value, $sub) !== false) {
      // store the key
      $result[] = $key;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}

var_dump(search_value($numbers, 1));
var_dump(search_value($numbers, 5));
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "one_digit"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "mixed_digits"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "one_digit"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution using `in_array` function:

```
$search = 1;
$keys = [];
foreach ($numbers as $k => $v) {
    if (is_array($v) && in_array($search, $v)) $keys[] = $k;
}

echo "I've found the searched value in ". implode(', ', $keys) ." subarray". ((count($keys) > 1)? "s":"") ." of \$numbers";
```

The output:

```
I've found the searched value in one_digit, mixed_digits subarrays of $numbers
```

Comment: @BogdanWebb this is the best answer on the page (you can omit the `is_array()` check; I would).  `array_search()` is overkill when you only want a true/false outcome from each subarray check.  You may want to reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

Check this and let me know if it helps you .

```
<?php
function array_find_deep($array, $search, $keys = array())
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $sub = array_find_deep($value, $search, array_merge($keys, array($key)));
            if (count($sub)) {
                return $sub;
            }
        } elseif ($value === $search) {
            return array_merge($keys, array($key));
        }
    }

    return array();
}


$numbers = array (
    "one_digit" => array (1,2,3,4,5), 
    "two_digits" => array (20,21,22,23,24,25),
    "three_digits" => array (301,302,303,304,304),
    "mixed_digits" => array (9,29,309,1)
);

var_dump(array_find_deep($numbers, 20));

var_dump(array_find_deep($numbers, 1));

var_dump(array_find_deep($numbers, 301));

var_dump(array_find_deep($numbers, 309));

?>
```

You can store the result in a variable like `$result  = array_find_deep($numbers, 20);` and try `echo $result[0]` which will give the result that in which array it found the value.